# Mongo DB C# Driver：How to reuse the existing filter for a new document?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a existing document call Bar which i have build serveral filter for it as Follow：

```
Builders<Bar>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.SomeString,"aaaa");

Builders<Bar>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.SomeInt,5343);
```

The definition of Foo, Bar is :

```
  public class Foo
    {
        public string TestString { get; set; }
        public int TestInt{get;set;}
        public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    }
    public class Bar
    {
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to resue those filters when Bar became a sub doucment of Foo.
Let say i have Foo document :

```
Foo foo = new Foo(){ 
TestString = "FooString",
Bar = new Bar(){SomeString = "BarString"}
                   }
```

How can i search foo by Filter :

```
Builders<Foo>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.Testring,"FooString") & Builders<Bar>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.SomeString,"BarString")//reuse the existing filter
```

Is there any api in MongoDb C# Driver available to  that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Usually collections for `Foo` and `Bar` objects will be separated, as GridFS does with `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` and one to many relationships. Supposing they reside in the same db called `foobar`:

```
var collectionFoo = _database.GetCollection<Foo>("foobar");
var collectionBar = _database.GetCollection<Bar>("foobar");
var f = Builders<Foo>.Filter;
var b = Builders<Bar>.Filter;
var filterFoo = f.Eq(x => x.TestString, "FooString") & f.Eq(x => x.Bar.SomeString, "BarString");
var filterBar = b.Eq(x => x.SomeString, "BarString");
```

**No reuse**, Bar is accessed as a dependent object of Foo. You are using a OR of [FilterDefinition{of Foo}](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Eq__1.htm).

2) Heterogenous collection containing both `Bar` and `Foo`. Bad design, imho. Query using `BsonDocument`. This is how you would write your filters: `var subDocBarfilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Bar.SomeString", "BarString");`
instead of: `var primaryBarFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("SomeString", "BarString");`. **You cannot reuse**, an embedded field is accessed differently from a primary one. See [Query by a Field in an Embedded Document C# driver Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/#query-by-a-field-in-an-embedded-document).

3) *Invent some common base type* for Foo and Bar. This will enable you to merge `FilterDefinition<Foo>` and `FilterDefinition<Bar>` and use a sort of factory. For instance `abstract class IHaveId { public int id  {get; set;} }`, with `Foo : IHaveId` and `Bar : IHaveId`.

```
string GetSomeStringFromBarFactory(IHaveId x) { 
    string s = ""; 
    if (x is Bar) s= (x as Bar).SomeString; 
    else if (x is Foo) s= (x as Foo).Bar.SomeString; 
    return s;
}
```

Then you will have to manage the `Func` to `Expression` conversion, from `Func<IHaveId, string>` to `Expression<Func<IHaveId, string>>`, *no easy/advisable task*.

```
Expression<Func<IHaveId, string>> expr = ConvertFunc2Expression (GetSomeStringFromBarFactory);
Builders<IHaveId>.Filter.Eq (expr, "BarString");
```

To sum up I don't think the current architecture of Mongo C# driver(version 2.0) allows or makes advisable such an abstraction.

Comment: Thanks to your answer！！